# VSTS Extension - Get build URL

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I'm developing a VSTS extension in Javascript.

In one of my tasks, I need to get a link to my build results.
I tried to read from {$Build.BuildUri} but it gives me `vstfs:///Build/Build/{buildId}` and not a real link.

How can I get a direct link to my build results? I need it both in build and in release pipelines.

Comment: What do you mean *my* build results? if I have 10 build definitions and each build have 10 build results, url of what do you need?

Comment: URL to the build results of the build itself during the build.

Comment: Are you creating custom build tasks?

Comment: Yes. I want to get a link to the build results page from my task.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The build result page use the URL formatted as below:

```
https://{vstscollectionuri}/{projectname}/_build/results?buildId={buildid}&_a=summary
```

And you can get these information via the [Predefined Build Variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/pipelines/build/variables?view=vsts) during the build. In your build task, get the following variables and then combine them to the build result URL.

> - System.TeamFoundationCollectionUri
> - System.TeamProject
> - Build.BuildId

Comment: Note that System.TeamFoundationCollectionUri will contain the http scheme as well as a trailing slash. The final string using variables is: 

`$(System.TeamFoundationCollectionUri)$(System.TeamProject)/_build/results?buildId=$(Build.BuildId)&_a=summary`